# Creating sub columns with a major column heading in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with columns in the following format[image]

I want to modify the column names like below:
[image]

Is it possible to perform this in pandas?

I tried multiple methods, but could not find any specific solution. Please suggest me how to perform this in Pandas.

Comment: Not it's not, you'd need to have 2 levels for all columns (you can however use None)

Comment: Yes, you can with levels. But you could also just have `embryo_gt.embryo_allele_66` and `embryo_gt.embryo_allele_33` as column names (or any other delimiter).

Comment: you could mimic the functionality by prepending the columns with the name of the major column, but it would essentially add some more code complexity when you try to filter through the data frame (though it would allow you to get all columns under the major column using something like - `filter_col = [col for col in df if col.startswith('major')]`)